# Rails/Passenger: no such file to load -- bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, bundler, ruby-enterprise-edition

I have an application running an old version of Rails (2.2.2) and Passenger that I got up and running using Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7. However, I soon found there were some incompatibilities between older versions of Rails and Ruby 1.8.7, and decided to downgrade to REE 1.8.6. However, now the application fails to start with a `LoadError`:

```
no such file to load -- bundler
```

I assume some path is not set correctly, but I'm not sure where to look. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much banging my head against the wall, I realized it was because files in /opt/ruby-enterprise-... weren't group readable (so the user running Apache didn't have access, I assume).

Comment: JR, funny that I should find your answer to your own question, was just searching for the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but a different solution.

In my deploy.rb file is a block like:

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0//bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 1.9.2',
  'GEM_HOME'     => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0',
  'GEM_PATH'     => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0',
  'BUNDLE_PATH'  => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0'  # If you are using bundler.
}
```

I pointed these paths to the new install of ruby (on the server), and it worked.